# HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH not working properly in firefox 4

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, firefox

I'm using this code to redirect my users, blocking ajax-only pages from their browser

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
    strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {}
else {
    header("Location: /");
}
```

It works fine on Google chrome, Firefox 26 and IE11, however in firefox 4, the header is triggered even when loading using ajax.

How can I fix this?

Comment: and when you var_dump $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] while using firefox 4 it is equal to ???

Comment: it returnes NULL in firefox 4

Comment: @Rooster it should return NULL when ajax is not used

Comment: That header is added by jQuery. If it doesn't work with Firefox/4 (a browser that's obviously no longer supported), you'll have to live with that unless you want to fix the jQuery code yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to either set the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header yourself, or set a different header and check for it also:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH",'xmlhttprequest');
            request.setRequestHeader("BACKUP_FIREFOX_AJAX", 'xmlhttprequest');
        }
 });
```

And then

```
if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') || 
   (isset($_SERVER['BACKUP_FIREFOX_AJAX']) && 
   strtolower($_SERVER['BACKUP_FIREFOX_AJAX']) == 'xmlhttprequest'))
```

Not sure if it will work given it's firefox 4 (really old version), but it's worth a shot.

Ok, on digging some more, there appears to be an old Firefox bug where 1) if an xhr gets redirected then the custom headers are lost, and 2) When "automatic proxy detection" is operating firefox will sometimes do an *internal* redirect which triggers the problem in 1.

So, you may need to do something other than a header... perhaps append a query string param to all outgoing ajax requests, I'm not sure if you'd need to modify the url directly or data for GET requests, so I'd just do both and hope it works:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
      if (settings.url.split('?').length > 1) {
         settings.url = settings.url + '&ajax=1';
      }
      else {
          settings.url = settings.url + '?ajax=1';
      }
   },
data: {
    ajax: '1'
  }
});
```

and then you could do:

```
if((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') || 
$_GET['ajax']==1)
```

Comment: Is there a way to impliment this without changing all of the $.ajax's in my code?

Comment: You should only have to do the `$.ajaxSetup` once - it will affect all of your `$.ajax` calls which happen after you run the setup.  Just make sure you run the `$.ajaxSetup` function before you run your actual ajax call.